# Flattr Auto-Submit URL fails with Invalid Request

Tags: flattr

I like to flattr an auto-submit url as the documentation describes on the bottom of the page:
http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/

Here is my request:

```
POST https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/flattr
Authorization: Bearer xxx
Content-Type: application/json

{"url" : "https://flattr.com/submit/auto?user_id=243&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmobilemacs.de%2F2012%2F01%2Fmm079-folgen-heist-maul-halten.html&title=MM079+Folgen+hei%C3%9Ft+Maul+halten&description=Die+erste+Sendung+des+Jahres+muss+gleich+den+Ausfall+von+Denis+verkraften+und+dazu+mit+einer+geradezu+j%C3%A4mmerlichen+Nachrichtenlage+arbeiten.+Wir+machen+das+beste+draus+und+reden+ausf%C3%BChrlich+%C3%BCber+Apps%2C+singe+die+leise+Klage+des+L%C3%B6wen%2C+geben+ein+paar+nette+Konsumtips+und+kritteln+an+jeder+Hardware%2C+Software+und+Websites+herum%2C+die+bei+drei+nicht+auf+den+B%C3%A4umen+war.+So+sind+wir+halt.+Zu+Beginn+begl%C3%BCcken+wir+Euch+mit+der+Aufl%C3%B6sung+des+R%C3%A4tsels+der+letzten+Sendung%3A+%09Wie+hie%C3%9F+der+erste+Webbrowser+von+Apple%3F+Antwort%3A+CYBERDOG+%28YE%29+%09Wie+lautet+der+urspr%C3%BCngliche+Projektname+von+Mac+OS+8%3F+Antwort%3A+COPLAND+%28LA%29+%09Wie+lautet+das+Root+Passwort+des+iPhone%3F+Antwort%3A+ALPINE+%28IN%29+%09Wie+hei%C3%9Ft+das+erste+Ger%C3%A4t+von+Apple+mit+einem+Geh%C3%A4use+aus+durchsichtigem+Plastik%3F+Antwort%3A+EMATE+%28EA%29+%09Wie+lautet+die+kleinste+Einheit+von+Bitcoin%3F+Antwort%3A+SATOSHI+%28ST%29+%09Welche+Waffe+in+Worms+Armageddon+ist+auch+ein+Codename+einer+Apple+Software%3F+Antwort%3A+HOLY+HAND+GRENADE+%28NGR%29+Aus+dem+sich+daraus+ergebenden+Buchstab&language=de_DE&tags=blog&hidden=0&category=audio"}
```

And here is what I get back:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is invalid","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"}
```

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: I just verified that the problem is not the url itself. I just tried **https://flattr.com/submit/auto?user_id=flattr&url=http://developers.flattr.net** as described as example for an auto-submit url in the docs and it doesn't work anyhow. HTTP response code is 400.

Comment: For testing, I just sent a **https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/user** request. This works without any issues. I have the feeling that the problem is on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that it took some time for us to respond.

It was a bug that now have been found thanks to you! :)

I've fixed it and rolled it out just now. I hope it works properly.

Let us know if you run into any other trouble.

Comment: I don't think so. Now I get status=403 `{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":"You are don't have sufficient access right to access this resource","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api"}` I also tried to change the authorization code and added scope: flattr. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the "flattr" scope for your bearer token?

Comment: Ah, it works now. My problem was that I added the scope parameter to the token request and not to the authorize request. Thanks for your help. Problem is solved.

Comment: I am getting the same error although I think I am doing everything right , I have "flattr" scope